# Rename columns of dataframe and access them with that name

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I have a loop that adds several columns to a data frame

I know how to rename columns with colnames, but I cannot use these new names to access these columns
E.g. I add a column to my frame with the number 22.

```
units = 10
my.frame[units+1] = 22
```

I can rename this column with:

```
colnames(my.frame)[units+1] = "twentytwo_column"
```

But if somewhere later in the code I want to access this column I have to do it like this:

```
my.frame[units+1]
```

It would increase comprehensibility if I could access it something like this:

```
my.frame[twentytwo_column]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure: `my.frame["twentytwo_column"]` or `my.frame$twentytwo_column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on basic object extraction (see `? Extract`).

You need to add a comma (and quotes) to your brackets to extract columns from a data.frame: `my.frame[, units+1]` or `my.frame[, "twentytwo_column"]`.

Also, typically `names` rather than `colnames` is used on data.frames.